# 48V coupling into digital signal

Tags: filter, power-electronics, decoupling, coupling

I have a large thruster that requires 48V to operate, which I've provided through an isolated supply (Vicor DC/DC isolated converters). The thruster uses a Hall-effect sensor to adjust the speed (-5V to +5V), and hands me back an encoder output that linearly relates to the screw speed somehow (though it's not clear yet how this works). The encoder output is actually a 0-12V digital signal that is powered off a provided non-isolated 12V input which should be isolated internally.

I've attached a scope trace of the relevant signals. Trace 1 is the isolated 48V line when the thruster is running, and trace 2 is this digital encoder signal. As you can see, it's incredibly noisy. I can physically isolate the signals but I don't believe that will help since the thruster wires run through a pre-wired bulkhead connection (MacArtney MCBH series, 8 wires), the wires for which run through a narrow slot all together that cannot be separated.

What I need to do is design a circuit that will filter out all of this noise and then step it all down to a standard 5V digial signal that my computer can read and decode. I'm looking for some help doing this because of the coupling; I've filtered out standard AC coupling, but this is different, I think.

I'm thinking a clamping circuit using two Schottky diodes will be the best start to remove most of the negative signal and that above the 12V. Then maybe a sequence of comparators?

Any help would be much appreciated!

[image: Thruster and encoder output traces.]

EDIT:

- The thruster power lines are twisted with their isolated ground, and the encoder output is twisted with its ground as well (these are separated).
- I can shield both pairs only to a point; beyond that all the wires run through a narrow choke point and cannot be shielded further.
- The encoder output is produced by some electronics internal to the thruster. This is, in fairness, unknown.

EDIT 2:

I've extended this question to the team I'm working with at large, and some good points were made, so I'll try to specify further. We didn't have a chance to verify, but Tony's point about the grounding is good - it's highly likely that the grounds were connected through the scope (see the attached diagram) and that's what caused the significant coupling noise.

So, given the clarification of the attached diagram and the realization that the noise will probably not be quite so severe, let's re-ask the question: **given the system shown in these block diagrams, how can we extract the 0-350 Hz square wave from the motor with as few components as possible?** Specifically:

- Assume the signal ground is NOT connected to 48v ground this time, and there is minimal conducted noise. Also assume there may be noise severe enough to produce momentary false falling or rising edges. Keep in mind that we have a very limited bandwidth of interest: 10-400 Hz.
- Assume the availability of 12v, 5v and 3.3v supplies for powering a filter circuit (passive filtering is preferred)
- Know that the signal could be fed into any of the following 3 interfaces to our CPU: a 3.3v logic input (Assume a digital input pulled to ground with an internal pull up of >10k. Reducing input impedance would only be possible with an external paralleled resistor.), a single ended non inverting unity gain amp (+/-15v tolerant) or differential input amp.
- Assume that our CPU interface has no hardware counters, zero-crossing or rising/falling edge detection circuitry. All inputs appear as bits in a register (either one bit for pin state or the output of an 18-bit ADC), and the only notification of their presence is a read-complete bit gets set.

[image]

Comment: Can you transformer couple the encoder outputs? If they are approximately audio bandwidth signals, there are professional audio components for the job - and relatively cheap by marine standards!

Answer (score 0):

**Noise is a result of many things:**  inductive signal coupling, conductive transients , inductive capture errors grounds from probe being to long, and lack of balancing noise from signals. (both need to be balanced and have low common mode impedance). Also reducing impedance of signals improves attenuation.

**Translated:** This means twisted pairs on noise thruster pair , CM choke with Pi filter caps to earth ground.  CM choke on long signals or shielded twisted pairs with earth ground shield. Learning how to measure a noisy ground with a scope and get a flat trace ( many examples in this forum, some which I have written). This is exclusively above 10MHz impulse type noise due to ground clip inductance length and 10:1 probe coax capacitance.  Ideal is remove tip and gnd clip and use pin and ring of prove between 5mm spaced test points with good grounds or A-B probing.  Floating grounds gives rise to common mode noise when imbalanced impedance.

**Summarized:** Balanced pairs, shielding, filtering, CM shunt caps on either side of CM choke.

This is not an explicit how to fix, since the how to create these signals was not given, yet the treatments are common and many alternative methods may work.

After you have considered these basics then you can consider filtering, and if needed opto-isolation.

Comment: Okay, this is all good information, but maybe I wasn't clear or I'm not understanding something. I've updated the question with some clarifications. I can try to get another scope to measure the noisy ground and try to get a flatter trace.

Comment: One or two chokes is not the same as a balanced CM choke.  The shield is connected to ground closest to logic ground only , not both ends.   Read here for better measurements. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/260595/mcp1501-voltage-reference-has-very-noisy-output/260596#260596  its not a bad scope. Just improper use.  A CM choke with  caps must be matched to load so we need that and all system grounds + photos to define better.  ( block diagram) Also earth ground noisy source helps absorb stray noise. A detailed block diagram would be really helpful.

Comment: Added a block diagram. Clarified situation. Load is a maximum 1000W motor.

Comment: Looks like the V high current pulses are a big loop antenna , maybe not wired that way. I suggest you use good logic output optoisolator and do all the other things I suggested.  If you filter the encoder out the LPG BW or rise time < 10% of min. pulse width or >3x max frequency. into opto. at Rx side.